# Get the full URL string via javascript. no luck with window.location.href

Tags: javascript

I am having an issue getting the full URL via the standard window.location.href method.

The full URL is: "http://fw.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025&pl=0&url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~"

using my script below it will return: "http://fw1.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025"

the information I actually need is a bit after that "url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw"

code:

```
<a class="email" title="Email US"  onclick="javascript:window.location.href='mailto:someone@mycompany.org?subject=Please review this website&body=The website that needs to be reviewed is located at ' + window.location.href;" style="color:red">click here to e-mail us</a>
```

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the URL parameter url from the current URL of the page you can use the `URLSearchParams`.

```
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const urlParam = searchParams.get('url');

console.log(urlParam); // Outputs "aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw"
```

Comment: easy peasy, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from this line, where you are injecting an unencoded URL into an encoded URI:

```html
<a class="email" title="Email US"  onclick="javascript:window.location.href='mailto:someone@mycompany.org?subject=Please review this website&body=The website that needs to be reviewed is located at ' + window.location.href;" style="color:red">click here to e-mail us</a>
```

Using the URL you've provided, the generated URI becomes the following:

```
mailto:someone@mycompany.org?subject=Please review this website&body=The website that needs to be reviewed is located at http://fw.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025&pl=0&url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~
```

The problem with this URI is that the `&` symbol (along with a handful of others) has special meaning in URIs. When you look at the parameters of the URI above, you can see that `url` and `pl` are parsed as if they weren't in the `body` parameter:

```json
{
  "subject": "Please review this website",
  "body": "The website that needs to be reviewed is located at http://fw.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025",
  "pl": "0",
  "url": "aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~"
}
```

To correctly embed a URL into a URI, you should pass it through `encodeURIComponent()`:

```html
<a class="email" title="Email US"  onclick="javascript:window.location.href='mailto:someone@mycompany.org?subject=Please review this website&body=The website that needs to be reviewed is located at ' + encodeURIComponent(window.location.href);" style="color:red">click here to e-mail us</a>
```

Now when that link is clicked, it produces the following URI:

```
mailto:someone@mycompany.org?subject=Please review this website&body=The website that needs to be reviewed is located at http%3A%2F%2Ffw.mycompany.org%3A9080%2Fips%2Fblock%2Fwebcat%3Fcat%3D1025%26pl%3D0%26url%3DaHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~
```

with the parameters:

```json
{
  "subject": "Please review this website",
  "body": "The website that needs to be reviewed is located at http://fw.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025&pl=0&url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It's just the `.href` property of the URL object.

```js
let str = "http://fw.mycompany.org:9080/ips/block/webcat?cat=1025&pl=0&url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw~~";
let url = new URL(str)
console.log(url.href);
```

Comment: The question was clear: "I am having an issue getting the full URL via the standard window.location.href method." The answer, precisely correct.

Comment: Apparently you did not read the entire question, or you would have seen this: 'the information I actually need is a bit after that "url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw"'

Comment: Please show me a page or scenario where `window.location.href` cuts off part of the URL?  I understand that someone said it does, but can you show me an example?

Comment: The question is badly worded and easy to misunderstand, but the OP seems fine with getting the URL, they were actually having difficulty getting a single parameter (also called `url`)

Comment: The URL is being cutoff because they using embedded JavaScript in an `onclick` to set a `mailto:` link.  Seriously dude, you don't seem to have read past the first two sentences of the question at any time.

Comment: The final sentence says "the information I actually need is a bit after that "url=aHR0cDovL3plbmRlc2suY29tLw"" yet you are saying that "they were actually having difficulty getting a single parameter (also called url) " Garbage in / Garbage out. It's fine. The title of the question says it all. I agree that I answered the question precisely correct.